# Navigation Obstacles and Mesh Region Area / Inaccuracy

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am attempting a tower defense style game using navigation for pathfinding. My navigation agents stopped moving when too many navigation obstacles were introduced to the scene. I realized that playing with the Min Region Area and Width Inaccuracy let it continue. However I have not found a good explanation of what these do, or how they affect performance.

How do these change navigation, and what are the performance considerations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those are described somehow clearly [here](http://ru.unity3d-docs.com/Documentation/Manual/Navmeshbaking.html).

According to it `Min region area` value is: "Regions with areas below this threshold will be discarded." So probably regions with just a little area are just left out of the search. You can control how big they are with this value. Could it be that you added so many obstacles that all the regions where discarded?

And `Width Inaccuracy` is "Allowable width inaccuracy". Which tells how much inaccuracy the computation can introduce to the `Radius`. Same document also states that "Increasing Width Inaccuracy allows for larger areas but reduces Navmesh precision."

This means that decreasing any of the two values will lead to more accurate navigation, but it also requires more computation time.

Comment: Ah, thank you.

How did you find that? Why is that not here, or linked to this?:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navmeshes.html

Comment: I don't know. Maybe that is older/newer version. I got the feeling that new manual entries seem to contain more text explanation and less advanced details.